# How do i solve object not found error message in R

Tags: r, validation, filtering, analytics, data-cleaning

I am trying to filter a dataset in R. I have installed (dplyr) package. I keep getting an error message that the column i am trying to filter cannot be found. I have checked the dataset name for spelling errors as well as the column name. I can clearly see the column "dose" in the dataset. I was expecting the dataset to be filtered according to the codeCan someone please help? I will share the code below and the error message.

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View (ToothGrowth)
filtered_ToothG <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View (filtered_ToothG)

Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found
```

Comment: Have you loaded `dplyr` by calling `library(dplyr)`? `filter()` is also a function in the `stats` package, which is loaded by default - you might be called the wrong version of `filter()`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have loaded dplyr and i am positive i am usiing the right filter function. I can tell because the other filter function starts with a F.

Comment: Also it seems like R cannot recognize/find any of the columns in the dataset.

Comment: Try changing `filtered_ToothG <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)` to `filtered_ToothG <- dplyr::filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5)`.

Comment: @Lewis21-10 `stats::filter()` does _not_ start with a capital F.  That's the base `Filter()` function, which is not what I said.  If you've loaded `dplyr` properly, the most likely explanation is you're subsequently loading another library with a function called `filter()`.  Either make `library(dplyr)` your last `library()` call, or try what Josh White said and explicitly use `dplyr::filter()`.  If you're in RStudio, put the cursor in the middle of `filter` and hit F2 to open the declaration of the version you're using.  The package name will be in the window title.

Comment: If you're not using RStudio, `find('filter')` will show you all packages loaded with a `filter` function, with the first package name the one being used